# How do you create a one to many relationship using mongodb realm web ui?

Tags: mongodb, realm

I have 2 documents one called clients one called jobs. I want to link every job to a client and a client to multiple jobs. I have managed to add a relationship from the job to the client using the client id. How can i link the client to every job using its ID?

This is my clients document schema:

```
{
  "title": "client",
  "properties": {
    "__v": {
      "bsonType": "int"
    },
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "surname": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "jobs": {
      "bsonType": "array"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my jobs document schema:

```
{
  "title": "job",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "client_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    }
 }
```

}

I want to have a jobs array under client that links to all the jobs with the client_id of that client

Comment: To start with, you would post the code and objects in the question so we know what you're working with! Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jay i updated my question

Comment: It's a good idea to include your coding platform as well as the actual objects from the SDK so we know what you're working with. Also, this is a cross-post over the the Realm forums. It's usually best practice to keep questions in one place so answers are consolidated and we are doing double the work.